# Ruby: String interpolation prints the function first when called second

Tags: ruby, string-interpolation

Here is my short program

```
def def1()
  x = 1
  puts x
end

def def2()
  y = 2
  puts y
end

puts "some text #{def1}"
puts "some text #{def2}"
```

The outcome of this example...

```
1
some text 
2
some text
```

I don't understand why this puts in this order and not "sometext" first.

Comment: Because `def1` within the interpolation is executed before to invoke `to_s` on it, after that it returns `nil`. Is the way `puts` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the string is created first, which means calling `def1`, and then the whole string is passed into `puts`.

We can expand `puts "some text #{def1}"` out to understand.

```
string = "some text " + def1.to_s
puts string
```

As you can see, `def1` is called to create the string. `def1` prints out 1 itself, it does not return anything (it returns `nil`). Then the whole string is printed.

That's how all function calls work. The arguments are evaluated, the the function is called.

You'd need to call `def1` after printing the prefix.

```
print "some text "
def1
```

This is a reason why it's often better to have a function return a value rather than print it itself.

Answer (score 1):

In order to print the string, `puts` has to know what the string is. In order to know what the string is in this particular line:

```
puts "some text #{def1}"
```

Ruby has to call `def1` first. `def1`, in turn, calls `puts` to print something.